# WebStorm keeps crashing my locally ran server because of Git's index.lock

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, reactjs, webstorm

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\ProjectDirectory\.git\index.lock'
    at Error (native)
```

I'm using WebStorm and everytime I run the local server for testing purposes using `npm start`, it crashes inevitably sometimes after doing nothing, and sometimes after making a change or so.

I'm using [this React boilerplate](https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot) and the actual author responded to a bug issue I brought up about this saying "Based on the error, it looks like either your editor or your source control system is locking files."

I'm a bit tired restarting the server every time I make a couple changes and would love to fix this.

[Full error log](https://pastebin.com/dCCEsrjc)

Comment: Is that a public repo where we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: @pedromss https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot that is a public repo yes

Comment: I'd like to see the actual error code; I don't think there's an lstat for Windows, nor does the POSIX lstat [have any EPERM error](https://linux.die.net/man/2/lstat), so I'm not sure what it's _actually_ invoking.

I recommend using [ProcMon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon); filter for accesses on files ending in "index.lock". This should tell us what process is trying to acquire information about index.lock, and what kind of failure they encounter.

To be honest, it's probably permissions. What happens when you run the command as admin?

Comment: @Birchlabs I'm running "npm start" on the Terminal provided by Webstorm on a Windows machine.  I'll try running WebStorm as admin and see if it makes a difference (though I'm not sure if that's what you mean exactly).  I can download ProcMon and try it out and see if it catches anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Only** IDE have reason to watch `.git/` folder. So if something else tries then it's a bug in configuration.

`npm start` is an alias for `npm-run-all --parallel test:watch open:src lint:watch`.

Make sure that `.git/` is exempted in their configuration.

Comment: i see.  can you explain to me how to exempt .git/ in the configuration for WebStorm?  i'll try figuring it out myself but figured to ask you as well

Comment: @user1189352 Webstorm have genuine reason to keep trask of .gif folder, as it can then take into account changes to working folder if You e.g. run some git commands from console. It's other tools that must be mis configured.